# Playing the same music on multiple computers

Tags: itunes

I have multiple Macs in my house. I'm looking for a way to play the same music simultaneously from both Macs. Each is connected to a speaker set, so I don't need bluetooth audio or anything fancy.

Comment: Free would be best. Poor college student and all that...

Comment: Burn the same data cd or use home sharing to get the playlist in both places is he "student budget" solution. Count down and  3-2-1-play is surprisingly effective if you have a long playlist and set it to repeat.

Comment: Haha, thanks @bmike. If the other options don't work, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @bmike That's a very good solution!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) does exactly what you ask.  The author charges $25 for more than 10 minutes of music (I know you said free would be good). A   [list of alternatives to Airfoil](http://alternativeto.net/software/airfoil/) exists, but i cant vouch for any other software.

Comment: Airfoil is _the app_ for this. Try it for free, buy it if you like it.

Comment: But she said free would be best, so... But if you want quality, yeah, Airfoil.

Comment: I'll talk it over with my roomies and see if we can make that happen. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly multiple ways to accomplish this, but what I figured out is the simplest free approach I know of: use [SoundFlower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/) (a free download from Cycling 74) to pipe your system audio to iChat, and use iChat to send the audio to another computer.

In your System Preferences go to Sound and set SoundFlower as both Input and Output. Note that this will make your system sound not go through your speakers, so to turn that back on also run SoundFlowerbed (the front end that comes with SoundFlower) and set SoundFlower's output to the speakers.

Now launch iChat and go to Preferences. In the Video/Audio preferences you can set what input to use; it'll probably be defaulting to your microphone but you can set that to SoundFlower. Now when you do a voice chat with someone else they will hear your computer's audio.